# Get Posts With selected tags using Prisma

Tags: sql, database, prisma

How can I get posts that have selected tags (filter by tag id) ?

Here are the models I'm using :

```
model Post {
  id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String
  tags  PostTags[]
}

model PostTags {
  id     Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  post   Post? @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  tag    Tag?  @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id])
  postId Int?
  tagId  Int?
}

model Tag {
  id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String     @unique
  posts PostTags[]
}
```

I tried to filter posts using this query but I'm getting also posts that have zero tags :

```
const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({ 
  where: { tags: { every: { id: { in: tags_arrays_ids } } } } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter posts and not include posts that have zero tags, use this query

```
const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    where: {
      tags: {
        some: {
          id: {
            in: tags_arrays_ids
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Notice how the only difference between your query and this one is the use of the `some` property. To learn more about it, check out the [prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#some).

Comment: This query will indeed return records having a tag where the id is in the array_ids but i want to get posts where every post has all the tags of the array_ids.
Let's assume we have an array of tags [1,2,3] 
You query will return a post with a single tag id 1. 
I want to filter posts that have all the tag 1, tag 2 and tag 3 in every post returned